# Use Azure AD B2C for WebApi auth in aspnetboilerplate from a SPA

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, aspnetboilerplate

I have a SPA web app written in Vue that is able to login to AADB2C directly without ABP and I get a good api token response for it.

For my backend WebApi project, I would like to use all of the nice features of ABP, but I would like to replace the authentication piece of ABP with AADB2C calls.  To do this, I replaced the AddAuthentication() call in Startup like this … (.net core)

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);  // ABP generated

    // I removed this code …
    //  AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);     // ABP generated

    // I added this code from a generated webapi project startup file that I know works separately …
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
       .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
...
}
```

How do I get ABP to recognize this and validate an external jwt token and create a new AbpUser?  It would be great to use all of the AbpAuthorize attributes on the abp app services this way.

I saw this advice, but it seems like I would need to call out to B2C myself this way …
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management?searchKey=authentication#external-authentication

Thanks

--Andy

Comment: Have you asked on the boilerplate forum? The question might be better suited there. https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5140

Comment: Thanks, since posting this, I realize that I may need to write a new module similar to this one to do this … https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/tree/dev/src/Abp.ZeroCore.IdentityServer4/IdentityServer4